# Characteristic maps of CW complexes

Tags: general-topology

Ordinarily John M. Lee's book "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" is a model of clarity, but on p. 131 I am very confused by the following text

"Given a cell complex (X, E) the open cells are typically just called the cells of X.  Be careful: although each e contained in E is an open cell meaning that it is homeomorphic to B^n for some n, it is not necessarily an open subset of X.  By the closed map lemma and proposition 2.30 (p. 30) the image of a characteristic map for e is equal to e^bar so each cell is precompact in X; but its closure might note be a closed cell because the characteristic map need not be injective on the boundary."

What does 'its' refer to?  How could e^bar NOT be closed?  What does non-injection on the boundary have to do with anything?  How could something homeomorphic to the classic open set (B^n) not be open?

I'm seriously confused by all of this and would like some help.

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed this question. I think I answered essentially the same question from the OP by email, but I'll repeat the answer here for public consumption.

> Ordinarily John M. Lee's book "Introduction to Topological Manifolds"
>   is a model of clarity,

Thank you!!

> but on p. 131 I am very confused by the following text
>
> "Given a cell complex (X, E) the open cells are typically just called
>   the cells of X.  Be careful: although each e contained in E is an open
>   cell meaning that it is homeomorphic to B^n for some n, it is not
>   necessarily an open subset of X.  By the closed map lemma and
>   proposition 2.30 (p. 30) the image of a characteristic map for e is
>   equal to e^bar so each cell is precompact in X; but its closure might
>   note be a closed cell because the characteristic map need not be
>   injective on the boundary."
>
> What does 'its' refer to?  How could e^bar NOT be closed?  What does
>   non-injection on the boundary have to do with anything?

The point of the phrase you quoted, "its closure might note be a closed cell," is that the closure of $e$ might not be a ***closed cell***, not that it might not be closed. Of course it's closed. But to be a closed cell, it would have to be homeomorphic to a closed Euclidean ball, and it might not be if the characteristic map isn't injective on the boundary. A good example to keep in mind is the map $q$ of Example 4.55: It maps the open ball homeomorphically onto an open subset of the sphere (which is therefore an open $n$-cell in the sphere), but it collapses the boundary to a point. So the closure of the open $n$-cell is definitely not a closed $n$-cell.

> How could something homeomorphic to the classic open set (B^n) not be
>   open?

Just take $X=\mathbb R^2$ and $e=\mathbb R \times \{0\}$. Then $e$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (and thus to $\mathbb B^1$), so it is an open $1$-cell. But it's not an open subset of $X$.

Jack Lee